# Terraform sha calculation happens before file created

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform script that keeps failing because I think it tries to calculate the hash of a zip file too early, before the file is actually created.
These are the relevant sections:

```
data "external" "my_application_layer" {
  program = [ 
    "../build/utils/package.sh", 
    "../packages/sites/my/application/layer/", 
    "my-application-layer.zip"
  ]
}
```

and

```
resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "my_application" {
  filename   = "${path.module}/../packages/sites/my/application/my_application_layer.zip"
  layer_name = "${var.resource_name_prefix}-my-application"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("${path.module}/../packages/sites/my/application/my-application-layer.zip")
  compatible_runtimes = [ "nodejs12.x" ]

  depends_on = [ 
      data.external.my_application_layer
  ]
}
```

what am I missing?

the actual error message is:

```
Error: Error in function call

  on my-application-lambda.tf line 50, in resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "my_application":
  50:   source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("${path.module}/../packages/sites/my/application/my-application-layer.zip")
    |----------------
    | path.module is "."

Call to function "filebase64sha256" failed: no file exists at
../packages/sites/my/application/my-application-layer.zip; this function works
only with files that are distributed as part of the configuration source code,
so if this file will be created by a resource in this configuration you must
instead obtain this result from an attribute of that resource.
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: oh, right. Updated the question.

Comment: What does your `package.sh` script look like?

Comment: it's a monorepo... but the build command in package.json for this particular project is: `"prod-install": "mkdir -p layer/nodejs && cp package.json layer/nodejs/ && cd layer/nodejs && npm i --production && rm package.json && mkdir -p ../../dist/node_modules && cp -r node_modules/@monorepo/ ../../dist/node_modules/@monorepo/"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your external data resource an output and reference it from the lambda layer so it has to wait until the package.sh script has finished.

package.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
SRC=$1
FILENAME=$2
cd $SRC
zip -r -X ../$FILENAME * %1>/dev/null %2>/dev/null
echo "{ \"hash\": \"$(cat "$TARGET" | shasum -a 256 | cut -d " " -f 1 | xxd -r -p | base64)\", \"md5\": \"$(cat "$TARGET" | md5)\" }"
```

Then reference the output from your layer

```
source_code_hash = "${data.external.my_application_layer.result.md5}"
```

Comment: that's it! changing the source code hash from sha256 to md5 worked! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Functions do not participate in the dependency graph, so the depends_on technique won't work here.

Here's one way to do what you need, with the archive_file data source zipping up the folder for you:

```
data "archive_file" "lambda_zip" {
type        = "zip"
source_dir  = "source"
output_path = "lambda.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "my_lambda" {
filename = "lambda.zip"
source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.lambda_zip.output_base64sha256}"
function_name = "my_lambda"
role = "${aws_iam_role.lambda.arn}"
description = "Some AWS lambda"
handler = "index.handler"
runtime = "nodejs4.3"
}
```

Comment: and that's the only thing I can't use because of an ongoing bug in terraform. This particular package has some special needs, and some of the symlinks are not followed during zipping. This is why I need to zip it separately.  I guess, I'll have to do the zip manually during build, and by the time terraform wants to calculate the hash, it will will be there. :(

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this is the bug that blocks me doing that: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-archive/issues/6

Comment: Note that building the `.zip` archive outside of Terraform is actually the recommended pattern in [the official guide on using Terraform with AWS Lambda](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/lambda-api-gateway). As that guide notes, "Terraform is not a build tool".

Answer (score 1):

In your `external.my_application_layer` you are creating

```
my_application_layer.zip
```

but then you are trying to use (wrong name):

```
my-application-layer.zip
```

Comment: good spot, but that's just the result of me being careless when I've copied over and made the names generic. I've updated the question.